# How can I auto-generate prisma CRUD operations?

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have a few models in my DB. I wanted to know if there is a way to auto-generate the code to apply CRUD operations on them - especially for those that have foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I get your question right. With `prisma generate` you can generate javascript API to run CRUD operations against your database.

If you want to generate a RESTful API with CRUD operations, take a look at e.g. https://github.com/kepelrs/nestjs-prisma-crud (requires Nestjs).

Comment: Is there anything without the nestjs dependency?

Comment: What stack are you using? If you are using postgres, you could take a look at PostgREST (https://postgrest.org/).